# Can we say anything about the limit of the Mill's Ratio for the Normal Distribution?

Tags: correlation, normal-distribution, density-function, cumulative-distribution-function

Is there anything we can say about $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{F(x)}{f(x)}$ where $F(x)$ is the CDF of the normal distribution and $f(x)$ is the pdf? I know this function is increasing, but what can we say about the limit?

More specifically, consider two random variables $v_b \sim N(\mu_b,\sigma_b)$ and $v_s \sim N(\mu_s,\sigma_s)$ with correlation $\rho$. I am trying to understand the existence and uniqueness of positive solutions to the following:
$$g(\pi):=\mu_b-\pi-\frac{\rho\sigma_b\mu_s}{\sigma_s^2}+\frac{\rho\sigma_b}{\sigma_s^2}\pi-\frac{F_{v_s}(\pi)}{f_{v_s}(\pi)}=0$$

This is not an easy task, but I thought understanding the limiting behavior of the Mill's ratio may help.

Comment: This equation doesn't seem to make physical sense, because it mixes quantities of various units.  *E.g.,* if $v_b$ is a length and $v_s$ a mass, then $\mu_b$ is a length, $\rho\sigma_b\mu_s/\sigma_s^2$ is a length per unit mass, and $F_{v_s}(\pi)/f_{v_s}(\pi)$ is a mass.

Comment: Why are you interpreting $v_b$ as a length and $v_s$ as a mass? This has nothing to do with physics.

Comment: I am not interpreting them as such: "E.g." means *for example.*  This is called the *units calculus*  or [quantity calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantity_calculus) and is useful for detecting basic algebraic errors in formulas.  The inconsistency raises red flags and makes me wonder whether this formula is really the one you want to be applying to whatever your original problem might be.

Comment: Got it, so does this imply there was a mistake somewhere? As in, this equation doesn't make intuitive sense at all?

Comment: Yes, that's my concern, but I can't advise you because I don't know where this equation came from or what it is intended to mean.

Comment: Does your intuition that this equation doesn't make sense still apply if this is an economics equation? I.e. I am modeling an economic interaction

Comment: It does.  However, there are circumstances in which it would make sense.  For instance, when there is no choice of the units of measurement in which to express the variables.

Answer (score 1):

I may be missing something, but, I think the answer here is straightforward.

as $x \rightarrow \infty$; $F(x) \rightarrow 1$ and $f(x)\rightarrow 0$. Thus the Mills ratio $\frac{F(X)}{f(x)}$ will go to infinity.

The other case is a bit more interesting. when $x \rightarrow -\infty$, $F(x) \rightarrow 0$ and $f(x)\rightarrow 0$. So you need l'hopital's rule.

$$\frac{F(X)}{f(x)}|_{x\rightarrow -\infty} = \frac{F'(x)}{f'(x)}=\frac{f(x)}{-x*f(x)}=\frac{1}{-x}$$

So
$$\frac{F(X)}{f(x)}|_{x\rightarrow -\infty}\rightarrow 0$$